Representations of Kac-Moody Lie algebra
Lat $\mathfrak g$ be a Kac-moody Lie algebra. I know that if $\mathfrak g$ is symmetrizable, then any integrable highest weight $\mathfrak g$-module is completely reducible. Is this true in general ? Isn't true for any Kac-Moody Lie algebra ?

I'm a bit confused, what do you mean by symmetrizable?
